# Apply same height of div to other div's with padding on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 3 divs in a div.
**I want to apply same height of div to all the div who has maximum height.
Not just at first time but also if screen resizes as it's responsive.**

Here is my html

```
<div class="mid-box-mid row"> 
                <!-- Featured Box 1 -->
                <div class="mid-box col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="skt-iconbox iconbox-top">       
                                <h4>Population<br><span>Health management</span></h4>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="iconbox-content">       
Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.        
                    </div>          
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                </div>
  <!-- Featured Box 3 -->
                <div class="mid-box col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="skt-iconbox iconbox-top">       
                                <h4>Population<br><span>Health management</span></h4>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="iconbox-content">       
Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.        
                    </div>          
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                </div>
  <!-- Featured Box 3 -->
                <div class="mid-box col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="skt-iconbox iconbox-top">       
                                <h4>Population<br><span>Health management</span></h4>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="iconbox-content">       
Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.        
                      Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.  
                    </div>          
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.mid-box-mid{
    background-color:green;
}
.mid-box{
    background-color:red;
    padding:80px 40px;
}
```

javascript although right now it's static for the 3rd div's height.

```
$('.mid-box-mid >div').height($('.mid-box-mid >div:nth-child(3)').height());

$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('.mid-box-mid >div').height($('.mid-box-mid >div:nth-child(3)').height());
});
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/tp28419a/2/)

Comment: $(element).outerHeight()  -- returns the height with padding, margin and borders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a script I used often to do exactly what you're talking about.

```js
// The Function
jQuery.fn.equalCols = function () {
  $(this).css({'height' : ''});
  // Array Sorter
  var sortNumber = function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
  };

  var heights = [];

  // Push each height into an array
  $(this).each(function () {
    heights.push($(this).outerHeight());
  });

  heights.sort(sortNumber);

  var maxHeight = heights[0];

  return this.each(function () {
    // Set each column to the max height
    $(this).css({'height': maxHeight});
  });
};


//Usage
jQuery(function($){
  //Select the columns that need to be equal e.g
  $('.mid-box').equalCols();
});


// Adjusts DIV size on widow Resize
$(window).resize(function () {
  $('.mid-box').equalCols();
});
```

```css
.mid-box-mid{
  background-color:green;
}
.mid-box{
  background-color:red;
  padding:80px 40px;
  margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mid-box-mid row"> 
  <!-- Featured Box 1 -->
  <div class="mid-box col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="skt-iconbox iconbox-top">       
      <h4>Population<br><span>Health management</span></h4>
    </div>      
    <div class="iconbox-content">       
      Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.        
    </div>          
    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
  </div>
  <!-- Featured Box 3 -->
  <div class="mid-box col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="skt-iconbox iconbox-top">       
      <h4>Population<br><span>Health management</span></h4>
    </div>      
    <div class="iconbox-content">       
      Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.        
    </div>          
    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
  </div>
  <!-- Featured Box 3 -->
  <div class="mid-box col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="skt-iconbox iconbox-top">       
      <h4>Population<br><span>Health management</span></h4>
    </div>      
    <div class="iconbox-content">       
      Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.        
      Our Population Health Management helps physicians and their offices to strategically manage clinical and cost opportunities by improving overall healthcare quality of individuals care effectively and efficiently.  
    </div>          
    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried not working here is fiddle, am using fiddle as I can load bootstrap there http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/tp28419a/5/

Comment: It's working... there just seems to be else stopping it from seeing everything. Let me see what I can figure out with it.

Comment: Try that. I've update the fiddle and it seems to be working now. http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/tp28419a/6/

Comment: height is fixed, once you make screen bigger from small, it's height not becomes less. it should be optimized, with no extra space. that's the thing from am suffering

Comment: This is driving me crazy. The code is running on resize, but nothing is updating. It doesn't make since. Worry not though, I'm on it. I'll either figure out why... or I'll fix it.

Comment: Solved it. I've updated my post, but the solution is to remove the adjusted height, before adjusting it again. Otherwise it would think the initial adjustment is always the latest. http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/tp28419a/8/

Comment: it's prefect. It's what i was looking for, you saved me :) thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the .resize function. Your code will be executed every time screen size changes and will keep your divs size syncrhonized.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('.mid-box-mid >div').height($('.mid-box-mid >div:nth-child(3)').height());
});
```

please check this link to further reference:

[jQuery resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: I tried but in one of mine project it's not working good, it never calculates padding in it.